# Creating oAuth provider

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to build oAuth provider and started to do my homework around Facebook and Google, as they are the largest example there is I think. What I still don't understand, when a web site wants to use oAuth from Google or Facebook, does it have to apply their SDK or SDK is just to simple the hard work, but there is the way to do it your self from scratch? I asking this, because I wonder, if after my oAuth provide will be ready, I will have to create SDK as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to create any SDK for OAuth provider or clients. You can look at an [google's playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for a sample end to end demonstration of OAuth2 flow.